# VSTO переопределить метод

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Пишу AddIn для Outlook 2013. Использую VSTO. При наборе имени в поле "Кому" outlook автоматом из своего справочника автодополняет это имя. Так вот, стоит вопрос в том чтобы перехватить(переопределить) событие набора имени. Как сделать это с помощью VSTO?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Что за метод или событие отвечает за это?